# Using Eisenstein Series to represent the space of lattices - generalization to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, integer-lattices

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb R^2$. One way to represent this lattice is as a set of generating vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. However, this is a non-unique representation, as multiple vectors generate the set.

A better way to uniquely represent $\Lambda$ is to instead treat it as a lattice in $\Bbb C$ rather than in $\Bbb R^2$. We can then uniquely represent the lattice using the two Eisenstein series $G_4$ and $G_6$:

$$
G_{2k}(\Lambda) = \sum_{0 \neq \omega \in \Lambda} \frac{1}{\omega^{2k}}
$$

Since we are now treating the lattice vectors as complex numbers in $\Bbb C$ rather than vectors in $\Bbb R^2$, the above will converge to a complex number. It is then known that for any lattice $\Lambda$, the pair $(G_4(\Lambda), G_6(\Lambda))$ then uniquely represents the lattice. That is, we have that the map

$$
\text{lattices} \to \Bbb C^2 \\
\Lambda \mapsto (G_4(\Lambda), G_6(\Lambda))
$$

is a bijection (including degenerate lattices). There are many descriptions of the above online: [The Space of Lattices](http://www.stevejtrettel.com/the-space-of-lattices.html), [Lorenz and modular flows: a visual introduction](http://www.josleys.com/articles/ams_article/Lorenz3.htm), [n-Category Cafe: The Modular Flow on the Space of Lattices](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/the_modular_flow_on_the_space.html), etc. Serre’s A Course in Arithmetic, p. 89 is often cited.

**My question is**: How can you do something similar for the space of lattices in $\Bbb R^3$, or $\Bbb R^n$ in general? To get the Eisenstein series, we had to treat $\Bbb R^2$ as an algebra, so that we could take powers of vectors. Is there a different algebra, perhaps a Clifford algebra, that we can use on $\Bbb R^n$ to define a higher-dimensional analogue of the Eisenstein series?

---

The reason I ask is that this representation is very natural. The axis with $(G_4(\Lambda), G_6(\Lambda)) = (1,0)$ represents the square lattice with 4-fold symmetry, and the axis with $(G_4(\Lambda), G_6(\Lambda)) = (0,1)$ represents the triangular lattice with 6-fold symmetry. So, we basically represent the space of lattices as a "direct sum" of the spaces of rotated square and triangular lattices. We can easily see that the topology of the unimodular lattices is that of the 3-sphere, except for a trefoil knot representing the degenerate lattices. There are various Seifert fibrations representing [modular flow (image)](http://simonwillerton.staff.shef.ac.uk/ncafe/modular/Lattice12.gif) and so on.

The thing is that we got all this great structure only because we "cheated" and decided that $\Bbb R^2$ was isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. Phrased another way, all this structure resulted from us placing this nontrivial algebra structure on $\Bbb R^2$ from which we got the Eisenstein series. Doing so, however, gave us a very natural representation of the space of lattices. So it seems there should be a similar representation of the space of lattices in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Your map $\Lambda \mapsto (G_4(\Lambda), G_6(\Lambda))$ isn't a bijection to $\Bbb C^2$. It's not surjective. The Weierstrass cubic built from $G_4$ and $G_6$ has to be non-singular, so an elliptic curve. This means that an expression of the form $G_4^3-\lambda G_6^2$ must be nonzero (I'm too lazy to compute/look up $\lambda$).

Comment: Yeah, you want $G_4^3 - 27G_2^6 = 0$, which is the modular discriminant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Modular_discriminant). This curve is the trefoil knot I wrote about. The lattices mapping to this trefoil knot are the degenerate ones that don't span all of $\Bbb R^2$. The linked articles write about this.

Comment: Some comments: The standard answer to this is "Langlands's theory of Eisenstein series". I was hoping someone would answer this question with an elementary exposition of that, but as you can see from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205948 , not many people can.

Comment: I earlier posted some poorly thought out comments on Clifford algebras. Deleted until I have time to think harder.

Comment: Thanks David - I have looked at automorphic forms and the "Hilbert Eisenstein series" - are these the same as Langland's series?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Langlands' series are examples of automorphic forms, and that Hilbert Eisenstein series are as well; I don't think they are the same ones. But I have not succeeded in finding a source I can understand on this material. Also, I thought more about Clifford algebras, and concluded I had no good ideas about Clifford algebras.

Comment: Although I'll toss out a crazy idea that I'm coming to like. Here is a way to define $G_{2k}$ without ever mentioning $\mathbb{C}$: Remember that, given a polynomial $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a unique harmonic polynomial $H(f)$ which takes the same values on $S^{n-1}$. If $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$, then $H(f)$ has degree $\leq k$; let $P(f)$ be the degree $k$ part of $H(f)$. (continued)

Comment: Harmonic polynomials of degree $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are a $2$-dimensional vector space. If I identify them with $\mathbb{C}$ correctly, then I believe  $G_{2k}(\Lambda) = \sum_{v \in \Lambda_{\neq 0}} P\left( \langle v, \ \rangle^{2k} \right)/|v|^{4k}$.

Comment: Harmonic polynomials of degree $4$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a $9$-dimensional vector space, and the space of lattices in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension $9$. I wonder if there is anything interesting to say about the function $G(\Lambda) = \sum_{v \in \Lambda_{\neq 0}} P\left(\langle v,\ \rangle^4 \right)/|v|^8$. For example, does it embed $GL_3(\mathbb{R})/GL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ as an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^9$?

Comment: Hm - what does the notation $\langle v,\rangle$ mean?

Comment: Posted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334719/representation-of-the-space-of-lattices-in-bbb-rn?noredirect=1#comment836073_334719